# Chrome cut the text

Tags: html, css

[image: The text is cut]

This image is a screenshot of the address http://www.rothemcollection.com/engagement-rings/.
The 's' of 'Recommendations' cut by Google Chrome browser. I tried to change the z-index, move it down with the top or margin-top and it still cuts me to the end.
Does anyone have an idea? It could be related to poor I use a special font? If so, what should I do?

Comment: Can't see any problems in Chrome. Can you provide some code here, to reproduce the bug?

Comment: When I loaded the page w/ latest Chrome the "s" initially appeared fully, but then got "cut" by the overlapping images.

Comment: Exactly. The problem comes only when changing images.

Comment: view-source:http://www.rothemcollection.com/engagement-rings/ In Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the text size by one pixel and problem solved. 
Not a suboptimal solution but still works. Unfortunately, the solutions did not help.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css :

```
#mainSlider h1 span.big {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 63px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 484px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your **mainSlider Heading** `position:relative;` or define `z-index:1;`

**As like this**

```
#mainSlider h1{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

**Result is** 
[image]

Comment: The problem occurs only if the title ends just before the picture. If the trial will be longer, the problem is solved. But if I add a text not only gains real problem still exists.
It's very strange ..

Answer (score 0):

There is issue, most likely it is related to opacity and css engine rendering, supposely because of some optimization. I would suggest more the header to left by 6 pixels to avoid overlapping of images to it, something like this.

```
#mainSlider h1 {
   left: -6px;
   position: relative;
   ...
```

Comment: Although this will work, you may have gotten down voted for compromising design rather than fixing the issue? That's my only guess..

Comment: The problem occurs after the presentation begins

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this - I'll add my view to the mix. Try adding `z-index:-1;` to the `.ring` class. This will produce problems if you want to make the images links at some point, but should work in your current setup.

```
#mainSlider .ring{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```